# "Typical liberal bulls-t" or "typically liberal bulls-t"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, compound-adjectives, intensifying-adverbs, focusing-adverbs

My liberal friend wrote that he's gonna do some research soon.
I asked, "Into what?" 
"[Redacted.] Typically liberal bullshit," he replied self-depricatingly.
Then he corrects himself: "*typical"

But which is correct? "Typical liberal bullshit" or "typically liberal bullshit"?

Is typical an adjective or an adverb in that sentence?

Comment: I don't think I'd like your friend. I think it would be nice if people could keep political sneers out of Stack Exchange discourse.

Comment: Michael we're both liberals ironically mocking our own research interests. I think he and you would get along.

Comment: Tfw I use the word ironically incorrectly (?) on English language stack exchange

Comment: @MichaelHarvey https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzpndHtdl9A

Comment: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x17mm5b

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Typical liberal bullshit." **liberal bullshit** is the noun phrase, modified by the adjective *typical*.

The other phrase, *typically liberal bullshit*, would not convey the sense you are describing.

Comment: is "typically" not modifying the adjective "liberal"?

Comment: it would be an adverbial modifier but the noun changes from "liberal bullshit" to just "bullshit"

Comment: So both are grammatical?

Comment: both are grammatical, but grammaticality =/= correctness. the sentence "the commensurate dog ate the heavy sky" is grammatical, but nonsense.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean. Is "typically liberal bullshit" nonsensical?

Comment: it's not nonsense, but it is not the correct written form of what you are trying to express. "liberal bullshit" is the noun phrase du jour, and the crux of the humor at which your friend was getting; as a noun, it should be modified by a sole adjective. the difference is subtle and lost on most, so don't worry about misunderstood.

Comment: If you're right, what's fantastic about this is that my intuition was to say "typical liberal bullshit" but then I doubted my correct intuition and overcorrected.

Comment: your intuition was correct. you win this round ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can see what is going on by changing the sentence slightly, but using a more polite noun.

> 1. That nonsense is typically liberal.

Here the adverb ‘typically’ modifies the adjective ‘liberal’.

> 2. That liberal nonsense is typical.

Here the adjective ‘liberal’ qualifies the noun ‘nonsense’, while ‘typical’ plays the role performed by ‘liberal’ in 1.

Using a hyphen, the difference is between calling whatever had been said ***typically-liberal nonsense*** and calling it ***typical liberal-nonsense***:  not very much.  Both are correct grammar.

But are you sure the one word “typical” was a correction?  It could have been an exclamatory use of the adjective to apply to the whole thing, in effect repeating himself.

> Typically liberal nonsense.  Typical!!

Comment: You've persuaded me that @carly is dead on.

Comment: I think that making "typical" a predicate like this changes the meaning. "Typical liberal nonsense" refers to something that is a typical example of liberal nonsense, not to liberal nonsense that "is typical" in general.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, exactly.  I wish I had thought of that way of putting it.  And I suppose you could say that, using The adverb, he is saying it is a ‘typically liberal piece of it.  However, I am not sure that when we speak with this type of rage against all things liberal (or conservative) we are thing very hard about precise distinctions of meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Is the intent to say that bullshit in general is *typically liberal* or that this is the usual sort of *liberal bullshit* (but not of conservative bullshit)?  I suspect your friend meant the latter as liberals certainly do not have a monopoly on bullshit.

Comment: The latter. Which is another way of proving @carly right, I think - typical is a liberally used adjective modifying a typical noun phrase.